# 1D DCT matlab code

Tags: image-processing, matlab, discrete-signals, transform, dct

I was writing MATLAB code to compute 1D DCT of sample y.
On computing DCT for `y=[0,1,2]`, code generates coefficient `[3.0000   -2.2304 0 -0.1585]` which was consistent to coefficient generated by Matlab default `dct([0,1,2])`.

When sample `y=[1,2,3]` was chosen the same code didn't work well.

***Looking forward to modification and clarification in my custom DCT code.***

Eq DCT:

$$C(u) = \alpha(u)\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}f(x)\cos\left[\dfrac{\pi(2x+1)u}{2N} \right] \qquad\text{for}\qquad u=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1$$

**Custom code**

```
y=[0,1,2];
[M,N]=size(y);
sum=0;
dct1d=zeros(1,N);
u=[0:N-1] ; 
for j=1:N
    for i=1:N
        sum=sum+y(i).*(cos((pi.*(2.*y(i)+1).*u(j))/(2*N)));
    end
    if j==1   
            K=sqrt(1/N);
    else
            K=sqrt(2/N);
    end

   dct1d(j)=K.*sum;
   sum=0;
end
dct1d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mistyped the formula, replace this line

```
sum = sum + y(i).*(cos((pi.*(2.*y(i)+1).*u(j))/(2*N)));
```

with the one below, and it works fine.

```
sum = sum + y(i).*(cos((pi.*(2.*u(i)+1).*u(j))/(2*N)));
```

Comment: I voted for you, yet I am wondering whether it is a good idea to multiple a $u(i)$ by some $u(j)$. Same result here, but we lose the idea that inside the cosine, there is a time index and a frequency index (duality). Combining them cause issues with generalized versions (ie with different offsets in both index lists)

Comment: @LaurentDuval His style is his convention. However I can see that the integers *i* and *j* refers to time and frequency indices. He uses an array *u* for index remapping which I found as a clever thing...

Comment: The problem was to have $y$ both inside and outside the $\cos$. The philosophical question is: a unitless remapping for variables, or two distinct remappings with inverse units and same values

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I would write this DCT as:

$$F(u) = \alpha(u)\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}f(i)\cos\left(\frac{\pi u}{2N}(2i+1)\right)$$
We note that, with this 1-indexing of Matlab:

$$y[i+1] = f(i)\,.$$

Then I  would modify the inner limit (from $0$ to $N-1$ instead of  $1$ to $N$):

```
for i = 0:N-1
sum = sum + y(i+1)*(cos((pi*(2*i+1)*u(j))/(2*N)));
end
```

and you can remove the dotted operator as well.
I do prefer keeping the discrete time/space index $i$ better separated from the  discrete frequency index $u$, to preserve the symmetry/duality of the Discrete Cosine Transform, and that of its  inverse as well. This could be beneficial for extensions or generalizations of similar trigonometric transforms.